# Respecting DisplayFormat in custom DateTime template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, datatemplate, displayformat

I would like to create a custom template for displaying properties of the type `DateTime` while still being able to define the format using the `DisplayFormat` decoration in the class.

Let's say I want to surround every date with `>>` and `<<` using a template.
This would be the class:

```
public class Item
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    [UIHint("MyDateTimeTemplate")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy mm:hh}")] //no seconds
    public virtual DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

But using `>>@Model<<` as the `MyDateTimeTemplate.cshtml` template doesn't respect the `DataFormatString`.

I also tried `>>@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model)<<`, but this doesn't output anything (maybe due to a recursion loop because the template calls itself instead of the default?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

MyDateTimeTemplate.cshtml

```
<div>
  <span>>></span>
  <span>@string.Format(ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString, Model)</span>
  <span><<</span>
</div>
```

Comment: In case the `DataFormatString` is not set, you could also add a default, for example `@string.Format(ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString ?? "{0:dd.MM.yyyy mm:hh}", Model)`

Answer (score 1):

This is only a workaround, but if the template only consists of ">>@Model<<" maybe you want to create a HtmlHelper instead. Get @Html.DisplayFor in the helper method's body and then wrap that in >> <<. Something like this (haven't checked if the code works but hopefully gets you started):

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayWrappedDateFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime>> expression)
    {
        var originalDisplay = html.DisplayFor(expression).ToHtmlString();
        var newDisplay = String.Format("&gt;&gt;{0}&lt;&lt;", originalDisplay)

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(newDisplay);
    }
```